# Why is the "startup" configuration different with SQL Server 2022

Tags: configuration, sql-server-2022

From the Microsoft web page:

> SQL Server services are set to Automatic (Delayed Start) start mode
> In SQL Server 2022 (16.x), setting the Start Mode for a SQL Server service to Automatic in Configuration Manager, will configure that service to start in Automatic (Delayed Start) mode instead, even though the Start Mode shows as Automatic.

Does anyone know why they changed this? I feel like I should change it back to "automatic" in order to have my instance up and running as fast as possible but at the same time, there must be a reason why they did that...

I've looked at the Microsoft documentation but did not find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but a common complaint in the past has been that because Windows starts automatic services in an unpredictable order, SQL Server can fail to start automatically if it depends on other services (such as a file system service) that happened not to be scheduled to start before SQL Server.

Setting SQL Server to the two-minute delayed start is a pragmatic solution to this kind of problem.

If you know all the dependencies and can set them manually instead, do that.

If you don't have any such dependencies, feel free to set SQL Server back to automatic start rather than delayed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but based on my experience it's better to have it on Delayed start because sometimes OS starts services prior to a network subsystem and if you use active directory accounts as a service account or iSCSI disks as data disks SQL may fail because of missing network connection.